# To write parquet converted dataframe to adls zone 1

Tags: python

Here I am trying to write my parquet converted dataframe in to adls path and getting the following error, need help on rectifying this error. what am I doing wrong?

> TypeError: descriptor 'encode' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'bytes' object

Code:

```
df_str = df.to_parquet()
   with adl.open('data/file_name.parquet', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(str.encode(df_str))
     f.close()
```

Comment: is encode () should not be applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question code lacks the assignment/creation of `df_str`.

Its likely, you misinterpreted it to be an unencoded String, which is apparently not the case.

The short solution would be to try to use `f.write(df_str)` instead.

*In case this does not work, provide us with more code.*